# Show image name in Twig, relation one to one

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a one to one relation between `Player` and `Image`. I have also this line in my controller:

```
var_dump($players[0]->getLinkedImage1()->getName());
```

It shows the name of an image correctly.

And I have also this line in the template:

```
{% for players in player %}
  {{ player.age }}
  {{ player.linkedImage1.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I get this error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a NULL variable ("")

I expected the last line shown the same name as in the controller.

**EDIT**: finally I found out that the property was `public`, that was the reason. Anway I still understand it..

Comment: what if you comment the for loop and use `players[0]` instead?

Comment: @WouterJ I have this now: ``{{ players[0].age }}
      {{ players[0].linkedImage1.name }}``. The age is shown, but the name of the picture no.. But the name of the picture is shown in the controller..

Answer (score 1):

My bad ! 
Look your for loop..

Try 
{% for player in players %}

Comment: thanks, you are right, but happens something strange or funny even: only if I write ``var_dump($jugadoras[0]->getLinkedImage1()->getName());`` in the controller, the name of the picture is shown from the twig template ``{% for player in players %}  {{ player.nombre }} {{ player.linkedImage1.name }}  {% endfor %}``

Comment: I have tried in another action and template, but it happens the same: the image name is not shown, unless I write in the controller ``var_dump($jugadoras[0]->getLinkedImage1()->getName())``

Answer (score 0):

How did you write the property ? linkedImage1?

If you wrote something like linked_image_1 or linkedImage_1 you should call

```
{{ player.linked_image_1 }}
```

or

```
{{ player.linkedImage_1 }}
```

then twig will call the related getter according to : http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.html#method_camelize

If its a virtual getter you can directly access with :

```
{{ player.getLinkedImage1().name }}
```

or `{{ player.getLinkedImage1().getName() }}` `

Comment: I have this property:``/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Project\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Document", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $linkedImage1;`` If I write something different from ``players[0].linkedImage1`` I get an error

Comment: The name of the property does not matter, linkedImage1 is converted to getLinkedImage1...

Comment: and twig doesn't use symfony to determine the getter :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
{{ player.getLinkedImage1().getName() }}
```